# How can i find the difference between two List<List<String>> in java

Tags: java

```
List<List<String>> list1 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
List<List<String>> list2 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

the values in the list1 = [[cat,01,animal] , [mouse,02,animal] , [dog,03,animal] , [eagle,01,bird]]
the values in the list2 = [[mouse,02,animal], [eagle,01,bird]]
```

How can i output the common elements(mouse,02,animal and eagle,01,bird)
and 
the different elements (cat,01,animal and dog,03,animal)  using java.

Guys i don't think this is duplicate of comparing two list. Its list> comparison.

Comment: Why do you have an inner list if it only contains a single element?

Comment: well i have edited the question ..

Comment: In future basic Java questions, please do not anymore use `[java-ee]` tag. Moreover, please carefully read tag descriptions before picking tags.

Comment: How is mouse,2,mouse a common element in your example?

Comment: Alright ! The questions which is tagged along with this question as duplicate has the comparison between two arraylist or lists. Its the list<list<string>>

Comment: Could you please correct or explain your example in the question (regarding mouse,2,mouse)?

Comment: Have you actually tried to use retainAll? From experience, this should work.

Comment: retainAll is giving me empty output.. Where as removeAll gives me all the elements from the list1

Comment: The solutions given in the two duplicate questions [appear to be working for me](http://ideone.com/Fb6K1o) -- it's unclear to me why they aren't working for you. In particular, it shouldn't really matter if you're comparing a `List<String>` or a `List<List<String>>` -- the same code works for both. If I were you, I would consider editing your post to include the actual code you've tried using based on the linked posts and what the output is. You may have an unrelated issue or misunderstanding in your code.